# mysqli extension missing (Windows 10, PHP 7.17, MAMP,)

Tags: php, mysqli, mamp, php-7.1

So I have been searching high and low an answer to my problem. Anytime I go here
http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/, I get this error

So I created a php file with phpinfo() and get this

[info.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QQpn.png)

So then I go to my file explorer and follow the  directory
C:\MAMP\conf\php7.1.7

[Loaded Configuration File  C:\MAMP\conf\php7.1.7\php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF4a3.png)

Next I opened the php.ini file in sublime to make some changes (C:\MAMP\conf\php7.1.7\php.ini). I believe all the extensions are located at this directory

C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.1.7\ext

[where I think the php extensions are located at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcWTZ.png)

So these are the changes I make to my php.ini file (removing the ; from the front)

1)  ;Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.

```
extension_dir = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.1.7\ext\"
```

2)  ; Dynamic Extensions.

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

I restart my MAMP server every time I make a change and reset my browser as well. And I still get the same "mysqli extension" missing error

I have even tried adding some environment variable paths.....

[added two different environment variables

C:\MAMP\conf\php7.1.7 
and 
C:\MAMP\conf\php7.1.7\php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEiwI.png)

Also here is my new_connection.php file and code to connect to MySql

[new_connection.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STVbV.png)

This is what I get when I run the code (showing that both If statements are failing)

[mysqli_init function does not exist,
mysqli extension is not loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCL6g.png)

I found this
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

which states....
PHP 5.3.0 and newer 
On Windows, for PHP versions 5.3 and newer, the mysqli extension is enabled and uses the MySQL Native Driver by default. This means you don't need to worry about configuring access to libmysql.dll.

Which confuses me, because the mysqli extension did have a ';' in front when I opened  the php.ini file

Answer (score 2):

I used MAMP with PHP version 8.0.1 and the phpMyAdmin-Page always said that it needs mysqli to work. I searched every folder, commented a lot, always refreshed the server and so on but nothing worked...

... until I changed the PHP version to version 8.1.0 in the MAMP-settings and the extension_dir in the php.ini (path should be something like \MAMP\conf\php8.0.1) (the "extension_dir" should be in line 544).

Answer (score 1):

Solution for my case:

1. Windows 10
2. php -v shows 8.2x
3. MAMP set to 8.0.1
4. phpinfo() shows version of php 8.2x

Deleted php from PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution worked like this. My MAMP folder was C:\prg\MAMP

After installation MAMP had PHP 7.3.0 enabled, PhpMyAdmin was not working (same error message, mysqli extension missing), I switched to PHP 8.1.0, restarted everything, but still no success. I checked the php.ini file in folder
`C:\prg\MAMP\conf\php8.1.0`
and the extension directory was correctly defined as
`extension_dir = "C:\prg\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\ext\"`
but still I got the error

`The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.`

whenever I tried to open PhpMyAdmin.

So I edited the **httpd.conf** file in directory
`C:\prg\MAMP\bin\apache\conf`
there I saw a couple of lines with php7.3.0 instead of php8.1.0, so simply use find&replace to replace it with your selected PHP version and make sure those .dll files exist.
Also the PHPIniDir directive had to be modified together with LoadModule php7_module and the correct version of `php8apache2_4.dll` file instead of `php7apache2_4.dll`.
Here is the complete new code block:

```
LoadModule php8_module "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\php8apache2_4.dll"

<IfModule php8_module>
    PHPIniDir "C:\prg\MAMP\conf\php8.1.0\php.ini"
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
</IfModule>
```

After a complete MAMP restart it didn't work immediately, I got the mysqli error again, but a simple page refresh finally helped (browser cache?).